# Laravel return one model + association as JSON

Tags: json, laravel, associations

I'm looking for a way to return a model as JSON including an association model after save (within a controller).

I know how to respond as JSON with associations by doing the following :

```
$objects = MyModel::with(['assocation1', 'association2.dependencies'])->get();
return response()->json($objects, 200);
```

But in a case of an object already found ? I've tried to use the same concept as above but it returns every rows.

```
$object = MyModel::first();
$object->with(['assocation1', 'association2.dependencies'])->get();
```

Laravel's documentation unfortunately does says much about it. What I'm trying to do is to return a JSON object including an association after save, within a controller :

```
class ExampleController extends Controller {
    public function store()
    {
        $object = new MyModel($request->input('object'));
        $response = DB::transaction(function () use ($object) {
            if (object()->save()) {
                // Here I want to return the object with association1 as JSON
                return response()->json($object->with('association1')->get(), 201);
            }
        });
        return $response;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

More clarification about this case. Using either `with` or `load` seems to produce the same result: returning all rows from the `Object` object including associations. My goal here is to only return ONE object with it's association as JSON, not all of them.

Comment: can you elaborate more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you aren't as far off as you think. In your second example, you shouldn't call get(). Try this instead:

```
if ( $object = $object->save() )
{
    $object->load(['assocation1', 'association2.dependencies']);
    return response()->json($object, 201);
}
```